# XSockets - send binary data with metadata from server to client (browser)

Tags: .net, xsockets.net

Using XSockets up to date version (3), I can see in the documentation how to send binary data with metadata from javascript to the server (http://xsockets.net/docs/c-server-api#pass-metadata-with-your-binary-data). The question is how to do it the other way around - e.g. send metadata along with binary data from the server to the javascript client?